# Add mongoose query (promise) to array and do parallel operations

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, promise

I'm using mongoose to do some operation in MongoDB. I'd like to seach all tasks created by user, then set value `isPerforming` to `false` and save it.
Documentation says that mongoose query (with `.exec()` function) is promise. There's many tasks so I think to push them to array and do parallel save operations using `Q.all([...])`. The problem is when I try to do `.push()`. My code stops after first `.push()` operation. 
Is there any other way to do it?

```
 function stopUserTasks(userid) {

    var deferred = Q.defer();
    var query = Task.find({'_creator': userid}).exec();

    query.then(function(data, err) {
        console.log('found: ');
        console.log(data);
        if (err) {
          deferred.reject(err);
        }
        return data;
      })
      .then(function(data, err) {

        var len = data.length;
        var saveTasksPromises = [];

        for(var i = len; i--; ) {
          console.log(data[i]._id);
          saveTasksPromises.push(Task.save({'_id': data[i]._id, 'isPerforming': false}).exec() );
        }
        return saveTasksPromises;

      })
      .then(function(data, err) {
        console.log(data);

        deferred.resolve();
      });

      return deferred.promise;

  }// #stopUserTasks
```

Comment: Please don't use the [explicit promise creation antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). If you have to convert one type of promises (mongoose) to another (q), use `Promise.resolve(otherPromise)` or `Q(otherPromise)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Model.save()` returns **promise** actually, so no need to write `Model.save().exec()` so your line need to be adjusted as follow:

```
saveTasksPromises.push(Task.save({'_id': element._id, 'isPerforming': false}))
```

Also using `Q.all`, the whole function could be as follow:

```
function stopUserTasks(userid) {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  var promise = Task.find({'_creator': userid}).exec();

  promise
    .then(function(data) {
      var len = data.length;
      var saveTasksPromises = [];

      for(var i = len; i--; ) {
        saveTasksPromises.push(Task.save({'_id': data[i]._id, 'isPerforming': false}));
      }
      return Q.all(saveTasksPromises);
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      deferred.resolve(data);
    });
    .catch(function(err) {
      deferred.reject(err);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: It's not working. `deferred` promise isn't resolved or rejected. In console appear only first data._id. Of course `element._id` should be replaced by `data[i]._id`.

Comment: Check the edited answer above, after putting `Q.all` in action.

Comment: It almost work..  I figure out by myself how to do it thanks to yours suggestions. It works when in loop we change `saveTasksPromises.push(Task.save({'_id': data[i]._id, 'isPerforming': false}));` to  `var task = data[i];
            task.isPerforming = false;
            saveTasksPromises.push(task.save());`

Comment: Please don't use the [explicit promise creation antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). If you have to convert one type of promises (mongoose) to another (q), use `Promise.resolve(otherPromise)` or `Q(otherPromise)`.

Comment: @Tamas Hegedus : Thanks to point it out. I'm rookie but It isn't excuse to code in bad way :)